# How can I use Microsoft Surface SDK with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: wpf, touch, pixelsense

I visited [Surface SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716) and it tells that it requires Visual Studio 2010/Express. I tried to install it with VS 2012 RC but it does not allow. Does surface sdk not support VS 2012 RC ? How can I use it with VS 2012 RC ?

Answer (score 1):

Install the SDK 2.0 Feb. 2012 Update on a box with Win 7 and Visual Studio 2010. Then create a  Surface Project from the Template.  Change the Main Surface Window ( I forget the class name. ) to inherit from Window instead of Surface Window if you want it to work on Windows 8.  Of course doing this you will loose the input stack for Tags and stuff. Copy the Surface SDK redistributable Assemblies for the controls to a folder for future reference in new projects.  You could Upgrade the project that you create with Visual Studio to VS2012.  Create a template from there.  Hope this points you in the right direction.  I have not done it in a while and am writing from the top of my head. -Mark

Answer (score 1):

you have to reference the following ddls:

Microsoft.Surface.Core.dll,
Microsoft.Surface.dll,
Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Design.dll,
Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.dll,
Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.dll