# How to Develop Microsoft Surface Apps that Implement Gestures

Tags: c#-4.0, pixelsense

Good Morning All,

I am struggling to find basic/beginners resources on developing Surface applications for the Microsoft Tablet/Surface.

I can't even get the SDK to install against Visual Studio 2013?

Is there a tutorial somewhere where I can learn to how to create a basic swipe/touch interface for the Surface.

Cheers All,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

The SDK only works with Visual Studio 2010. I'm not sure why the MS Surface SDK hasn't been upgraded to work with later versions of Visual Studio...perhaps it's not doing that well in the marketplace.

Once you install the SDK, though, you'll have access to the [sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727916.aspx), where you will find plenty of samples that use gestures (now called "manipulations"). And if you don't actually have a PixelSense device, you'll want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24694805/603828) for how to get those samples to run on a mere touchscreen device.

Note that the shared multi-user desktop device that used to be called Surface is now called PixelSense, as explained in [this technote](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692162%28v=surface.10%29.aspx).